# How to display images from firebase storage with v-bind?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, firebase-storage, webpack-dev-server

I have a VueJS project connected to a Firebase database and Firebase Storage.

I have been able to put an image to storage and at the same time add a document to the database including the downloadURL of the image.

To retrieve data from firebase I make this call

```
db.collection("employees")
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data())
      const data = {
        id: doc.id,
        employee_id: doc.data().employee_id,
        name: doc.data().name,
        imageUrl: doc.data().imageUrl
      };
      this.employees.push(data)
    })
  })
```

The result of this call I log to the console. It shows:

```
{imageName: "efefe", imageUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-a…=media&token=9d2d7a1f-39b3-4582-8df1-f857aefc1a70", name: "jack"}
```

To present the retrieved data I use this template code

```
       <div v-for="employee in employees" :key="employee.id" class="slide">
          <b-card
            v-bind:title="employee.name"
            v-bind:src="employee.imageUrl"
            style="min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem;"
            class=""
          >
          </b-card>
        </div>
```

All of the employees are presented including their names but without the image.

I read about a possible Webpack issue which can be solved by wrapping the v-bind:src value with require(''). I have tried that but it doesn't work, I get a terminal error that the dependency was not found.

I have been at this problem for a few hours and can not get it to work.

Can someone please provide have a look. I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked [bootstrap-vue document](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/card/), it should be `img-src` instead of `src`

```
<b-card
     v-bind:title="employee.name"
     :img-src="employee.imageUrl"
     style="min-width: 15rem; max-width: 15rem;"
     class=""
   >
</b-card>
```

Comment: Sometimes you are so stuck that you have no sight on the tiniest faults. Thank you for having a look.
After this, a broken image was presented. It turned out I had to specify a storage rule to allow to read from the db for anonymous users.

It worked. Thank you.